# How and which applications come under MDM configuration profile

Tags: ios, mdm

After MDM enrollment mdm configuration profile gets installed in device but what is the parameter which decide about which applications will come under this mdm configuration profile.To be more precise, suppose mdm configuration profile got installed on my device(we can check in General>Device management) and now whatever application i installed through that will come under that configuration profile in the **Apps** section.So my question is all the applications which we install will not come under that profile.So i want to know what is the parameter which decide which application will be under mdm profile and which app will be out of it.

Second Question:

I tried one test case which is showing some other response, i will explain it step by step:

1. I installed MDM configuration profile on my device, which prompted me to install an application and i installed it successfully.The application has gone inside the configuration profile in Apps section.
2. Then i manually deleted the application.
3. Then i installed the same application(with same distribution certificate) through my mac and it again gone inside the same configuration profile inside Apps section.

If you are saying that only the applications which are installed through Install app command will be managed then how the application which i installed through Mac system(same application) directly is going into that configuration profile?
I think there is some link of that provisioning profile with the configuration profile.

Thanks for your answers in advance(-:

Answer (score 2):

It is neither. Once the device management profile gives is installed on the device, the MDM server has permission to install and remove managed apps.

Once the profile is installed the MDM is authorised to send management commands to the device. One of the commands it can send is the command to install/manage an app.  [managed application commands](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH3-SW52)

If the MDM attempts to install an app that is already installed then the user will be prompted to allow that app to become managed by the MDM if the `ChangeManagementState` property of the request is set to *managed*.

Although the list of managed apps appears in settings under the profile, the apps are not directly part of the profile that is delivered to the device, they are simply associated with the profile once the MDM issues the install managed app command.

Comment: Please read the question again, i think you did not get the question.

Comment: No, I understand the question.  There is no parameter of the profile that determines which apps are managed.

Comment: I tried one test case which is showing some other response, i will explain it step by step:
1. I installed MDM configuration profile on my device, which prompted me to install an application and i installed it successfully.

Comment: Here is the list of payloads that can be part of the profile - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW35 You will see that there is no application delivery payload.  What happened when you installed the profile is that the device checked in to the MDM immediately and in response the MDMsent an application install command.  This happened very quickly, so it looked like the profile installed the app, but it didn't; The profile gave the MDM permission to install apps.

Comment: Thankyou for your response,but i have one more question.I am editing the question Please reply.

Comment: I have already covered that in the last paragraph of my answer; When the MDM installs a managed app, the OS associates that app with the profile.  If you delete and re-install the app that association is still there, so the app immediately becomes managed if you install it again, but there is nothing in the profile itself that contains the list of managed apps.

Comment: Great, Thank you for your nice reply.
Can you please share if there is any documents regarding this?

Comment: I have already linked to the MDM command documents and there is this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/2-MDM_Check_In_Protocol/MDM_Check_In_Protocol..html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH4-SW2